# FileInfo.CopyTo fails without an Exception

Tags: .net, file-io

I'm running into a bizarre situation that I'm hoping some here can solve. I've written a FileSystemWatcher-based app for a client, and after it processes each file it should move the file to a good or bad folder. The issue is the client uses AD, which I can't test locally, and apparently there must be some kind of rights issue that isn't being reported back to my program so it is deleting the file (the next operation) even though the copy didn't succeed. Nothing is being written to my logfile so no Exception is being generated. I have tested my program locally with mapped drives and UNC paths and it works fine for me. Source is VB.Net but I don't believe that is relevant.

```
''' <summary>
''' Moves a file to one of two folders by overwriting the destination and deleting the source
''' </summary>
''' <param name="name">Full path of filename</param>
''' <param name="good">Whether file is moved to good or bad folder</param>
''' <remarks>good should only be true if data was successfully saved.
''' This would include unique key failures because of multiple attempts with the same file.</remarks>
Private Sub moveFile(name As String, good As Boolean)
    Dim targetFileName As String
    Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(name)

    Try
        If good Then
            updateStatus("Moving file to Good")
            targetFileName = Path.Combine(ProcessedFilesBaseFolder, "ProcessedFiles", "Good", fi.Name)
        Else
            updateStatus("Moving file to Bad")
            targetFileName = Path.Combine(ProcessedFilesBaseFolder, "ProcessedFiles", "Bad", fi.Name)
        End If

        fi.CopyTo(targetFileName, True)
        fi.Delete()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'It is possible duplicate processing attempts on the same file could be expected to be "normal"
        LogErr(ex.Message, True, LogLevel.ERR)
    End Try

End Sub
```

The two directories are created at program start if they don't exist. Run As Administrator... doesn't help. Target is 4.5.2.

Why is an Exception not being thrown?

Comment: Reads like a file permission issue. I don't know how you LogErr works and this might sound like a silly idea, but if the message is blank will it still write the log? Might there be some information in an inner exception? Are any other parts of the application writing to your log? could it be a write permission on log file if nothing is being written. Not sure I'm adding anything useful, but sometimes we are so close to issue we are blind.

Comment: @Mayhem50 Yes, other things are written to the log, and it would write a blank message if ex.Message was empty for some reason. In my tests it would write if it couldn't copy for some reason (i.e., unplug cable).